# Central hub for Computer/TV/Video Game systems/etc?

Tags: networking, display, tv, desktop-computer, hub

I have the following devices:

- TV (Inputs: HDMI + DVI)
- Xbox 360 (Outputs: HDMI Audio/Video)
- Desktop PC (Outputs: HDMI + DVI Video; 1/8" mini cable out Audio)
- Two LCD PC monitors (Outputs: DVI Video)

And I have two rooms I would like to use these devices in:

- Living Room (contains TV + Xbox 360)
- Bed Room (contains PC + monitors)
- Both rooms are adjacent to each other.

I would like to play my PC games on my TV. Conversely, I would like to play my Xbox 360 on my PC monitors. Is there any way to have some sort of central hub/switch system that I can send different video/sound signals to either the TV setup or Monitor setup? Especially given my PC outputs Video through the video card and Audio through a sound card?

Bonus points for incorporating a NAS into this system. Thanks for the suggestions! (I apologize if there's a better SE site for this to go into.)

Comment: Your main question's easy (hdmi switching, as suggested previously by others), the NAS part however is confusing. Is being able to access it with your xbox/pc not enough, or is that not what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

you need something like this [HDMI Switching](http://www.monoprice.com/Product/?c_id=101&cp_id=10110&cs_id=1011002&p_id=7112&seq=1&format=1#largeimage)

forgot to mention that you can get HDMI to DVI converter for the screens that don't take HDMI

Comment: The HDMI switch is a good suggestion. Forgot about those. Is there any solution that would take into account that my PC has separate Audio and Video outputs?

Comment: you would need something like this BYTECC HM108 DVI + Audio to HDMI® Converter, [link](http://www.rakuten.com/prod/bytecc-hm108-dvi-plus-audio-to-hdmi-converter/230512062.html?listingId=302608379)